# How to change MessageBox.Icon

Tags: .net, messagebox

Does anyone knows how to change icons of MessageBox? I want to change to some icons made by me.

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That is not possible, `MessageBox` supports only the few basic icons.

You'll have to design your own `MessageBox`-esque dialog.